# Difference between timeout and connect_timeout options on Ruby Mongo driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb

We need to set a timeout value when connecting to Mongo via Ruby. We're on Mongo 2.2.

Should we use `:timeout` or `:connect_timeout`? We see code snippets using both options here on SO and elsewhere. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see what the different timeouts are here:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb#L104

Copying from there:

> ```
> #  @option opts [Float] :timeout (5.0) When all of the self.connections a pool are checked out,
> #    this is the number of seconds to wait for a new connection to be released before throwing an exception.
> #    Note: this setting is relevant only for multi-threaded applications.
> #  @option opts [Float] :op_timeout (nil) The number of seconds to wait for a read operation to time out.
> #    Disabled by default.
> #  @option opts [Float] :connect_timeout (nil) The number of seconds to wait before timing out a
> #    connection attempt.
> ```